# Maven: Resolving Duplicate Dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I'm developing an application that will be used internally at our company. In order for it to interop with our other internal systems I have to use some maven dependencies that we use internally, but this is causing some issues with using some external 3rd party dependencies that I also need.

So essentially my pom looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        internal-framework-artifact
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        necessary-third-party-artifact
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've come to find that both of these dependencies have the apache's `commons-collections` as one of their own dependencies (among a large number of others, but we'll just keep it at one for this question's simplicity).

If I place exclusion rules on both of them for the `commons-collections` pom I can compile the project, but my resulting jar won't have access to either version of `commons-collections` and will just result in a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception. Removing the exclusion rule on either of them just results in a mvn compiler error:

> [WARNING] Rule 2: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BanDuplicateClasses failed with message:
>   Duplicate classes found:

I've been looking through various so q/a's and I can't really seem to find something that's 100% relevant to my situation. I'm really at a loss as to how to resolve this. Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: Like I mentioned, excluding it from only one of them causes the maven error I quote above. I don't know why or what to do about that; which is really the point of my question.

Comment: I suggest you do this `mvn dependency:tree -Doutput=/path/to/file` and examine the results.

Comment: Have you tried exclusions on both plus a dependency of your own for commons-collections? This should compile and keep your jar happy. If this produces run-time errors, you probably need to upgrade one or the other framework.

Comment: The warning is not a mvn compiler error. It is a mvn enforcer error, which is slightly different. Does a mvn enforcer:enforce with -X show any hints as to where it finds the duplicate classes? Otherwise look at the full dependency tree as @BevynQ suggests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never actually used the `maven-shade-plugin` for shading, but I think this is the exact use case it was designed for.

Create a new project that uses the `maven-shade-plugin` (see: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to produce an uber-jar version of `internal-framework-artifact` which contains that classes in `internal-framework-artifact` and all its dependencies.  Configure the plugin so that it relocates all the classes that are also dependencies of `necessary-third-party-artifact` to some non-conflicting package names.  This new project should produce a .jar with a different name, something like `internal-framework-artifact-with-dependencies`.

Now modify your original pom so that it is dependent on `internal-framework-artifact-with-dependencies` instead, and it should work.